# How to use ImportJSON to pick the BTC Latest Price from BitBNS?

Tags: json, import

I am trying to ImportJson function on my Google sheet to pull their Public Information of latest BTC Price.

But, I am not able to get it work.

Following is their Public Json Format Http Request URL:
https://bitbns.com/order/getTickerWithVolume/

Following is the ImportJSON function I am trying:

```
=importJSON("https://bitbns.com/order/getTickerWithVolume","/BTC","0.last_traded_price")
```

Please note: I am already installed the IMPORTJSON script in Google Sheet and I able to pull data from other Public API address.

Comment: Can I ask you about the result you expect? Unfortunately, from `pull their Public Information of latest BTC Price`, I cannot understand about your goal. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: I am trying to get the latest price of BTC from that exchange

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `the latest price of BTC`, is this the value of `last_traded_price` in the object of `BTC`?

Comment: Yes, if you visit the GET request URL here (https://bitbns.com/order/getTickerWithVolume/) You will notice that "last_traded_price" is the variable for the BTC PRICE.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I thought that I could understand about your goal. So I proposed a modified formula as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

### Question 1:

- You want to retrieve the value of `last_traded_price` in the object of `BTC` from the URL of `https://bitbns.com/order/getTickerWithVolume/` using ImportJSON.

I could understand like above.

#### Modified formula:

```
=importJSON(A1,"/BTC/last_traded_price", "noInherit,noTruncate,noHeaders")
```

- `https://bitbns.com/order/getTickerWithVolume` is put in the cell "A1".
- In this case, `/BTC/last_traded_price` is used as the path.

#### Result:

[image]

#### Reference:

- [ImportJSON](https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON)

### Question 2:

- You want to retrieve the latest value of `p` from the object of `https://public.coindcx.com/market_data/trade_history?pair=B-BTC_USDT`.

When I saw the object of `https://public.coindcx.com/market_data/trade_history?pair=B-BTC_USDT`, it was found that the 1st index of the array is the latest value. By this, how about the following sample formula?

#### Sample formula:

```
=INDEX(importJSON(A1, "/p","noInherit,noTruncate,noHeaders"),1)
```

- `https://public.coindcx.com/market_data/trade_history?pair=B-BTC_USDT` is put in the cell "A1".

### Note:

In above 2 answers, I think that above answer might not be able to be used for other objects with the other structure except for the objects retrieved by above URLs. Please be careful this. I apologize that I cannot propose one formula which can be used for the objects with the various structures.

Comment: Thanks... This works great. I was using the ImportJSON code from here: https://blog.coingecko.com/import-coingecko-cryptocurrency-data-into-google-sheets/ This was simplified to use the "xpath". But, the ImportJSON, code you refered me looks much better.

Comment: However, after using your refereed codes, I am having issue with one site I was fetching the JSON. I am trying to fetch the "p" value for the latest time - https://public.coindcx.com/market_data/trade_history?pair=B-BTC_USDT When I use your method, its fetching and displaying all the Value of "p" rather just for the latest Time Stamp in "t". =importJSON("https://public.coindcx.com/market_data/trade_history?pair=B-BTC_USDT","/p","noInherit,noTruncate,noHeaders")

Comment: As there are multiple "p" in the JSON text, is it possible, to fetch the only one "p" value with the latest TimeStamp in "t"??? https://public.coindcx.com/market_data/trade_history?pair=B-BTC_USDT

Comment: @Joney Walker Thank you for replying. About your new question, I added one more answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.